# Xbox UWP Memory Snapshot Crashes

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, uwp, visual-studio-2019, xbox-one

When running my UWP Xbox one app with the debugger attached, if I try to take a snapshot it begins counting memory objects and then the app closes and the debugger disconnects. I tried using Visual Studio 2017, as well as Visual Studio 2019 and I also tried repairing my Visual Studio installations. Both versions exhibit the same behavior.
[image: Snapshot button]
[image]
[image: network connection lost]

Comment: I tested remote debugger in Visual Studio 2019 and take snapshot, it works well, I suppose there are some issues in your VS 2017. Please try to repair VS2017 or debug in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I've repaired both versions and tried the same thing in both. They show the same behavior. This leads me to think there is something else going on.

Comment: @emd Hi emd, any update for this issue? I tried the remote-debugging for xbox in both VS2017 and VS2019, but can't reproduce same issue. Please check if this issue persists if you create a new simple xbox project. And make sure you've updated vs2017 and vs2019 to latest versions and your app targets x64.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Memory snapshotting on a blank app deployed to the same device works as expected. Any idea why a certain project would cause this? All are set to target x64 and I'm running VS 2019 16.1.6

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-on-a-remote-machine?view=vs-2019). Haven't seen this behavior before, what network do you use? Make sure using the wired network instead of wifi.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT My team has both wired and wireless setups and we see the same behavior across entirely separate setups. I took a look at the document you linked and it seems to be in line with what we used [over here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/development-environment-setup)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the issue persists? And if it exists in your machine or also your fellows's.